# Re-auth user and try get request. Angular 9

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, rxjs

I have some code for login, setToken in app storage and request for some data.

CODE HERE -> http://codeshare.io/al8K9D

```
//my function where i take list for view
getAll(page, reportStart?: string, reportEnd?: string): Observable<Visit[]> {
    return this.http.get('https://' + this.domain + '/backend-api/tasks/reports/index?PHPSESSID='+this.PHPSESSID+'&rf[report_start]='+reportStart+'&rf[report_end]='+reportEnd+'&page='+page
      ).pipe(map(data => {
            let visitsList = data['visits_grid']
            return visitsList.map(function(visit:any) {
                return {name: visit.client_facility, date: visit.date_start, hash: visit.hash}
        })
    }),
}

// login method 
login(user: User): Observable<any>{
    const body = new HttpParams()
      .set('email', user.email)
      .set('password', user.password);

    return this.http.post('https://'+this.domain.value+'/backend-api/user/login',
      body.toString(),
      {
        headers: new HttpHeaders()
          .set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
      }).pipe(tap(response => {
        if (response['session_id']) {
          this.setToken(response)
        } else {
          this.onError()
        }
      }), catchError(this.handleError.bind(this)))
  }  
  
  //after login i use setToken to save him in app for next requests
  public setToken(response) {
    console.log('setToken')
    if (response != null) {
      this.storage.set('PHPSESSID', response['session_id']).then(() => {
          this.PHPSESSID.next(response['session_id'])
          this.authState.next(true)
        })

    } else if (response == null) {
      this.authState.next(false)
    } 
  }
```

Now if my PHPSESSID is died i logout my user but need to autorelogin and use new PHPSESSID in request params

I tried to do it through retryWhen() but nothing worked

How can I implement this?

Comment: Ok________Ready

Comment: Since you logout when the session has died and you then want to re-login, where is that part of the code? Where do you check for session expired

Comment: Before that, getting an error in the request, I logged out the user (this is in the getAll, catchError), but this is not what I need. If you receive an error, login again and use the new received PHPSESSID in the request (in getAll function). So that the user does not re-login and immediately receive a response using a new PHPSESSID